# Challenging mysql INTERSECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the mutual contacts between two users. The contacts table is set up like this:

```
userprofile_usercontact
- first_user_id
- second_user_id
- mutual
```

The following is the query I am trying to achieve:

```
/* get the first user's contacts */
SELECT second_user_id FROM userprofile_usercontact WHERE first_user_id = 1 AND mutual = 1
   UNION 
SELECT first_user_id FROM userprofile_usercontact WHERE second_user_id = 1 AND mutual = 1
    *INTERSECT*
/* get the second user's contacts */
SELECT second_user_id FROM userprofile_usercontact WHERE first_user_id = 37 AND mutual = 1
    UNION 
SELECT first_user_id FROM userprofile_usercontact WHERE second_user_id = 37 AND mutual = 1
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the significance of the mutual attribute - but since it's always 1 in your example code, to find the common contacts (single degree of seperation) between $user1 and $user2 it's just a matter of (inner) joining the data.

```
SELECT user1_contacts.uid
FROM
(SELECT a.first_user_id as uid
 FROM userprofile_usercontact a
 WHERE a.second_user_id=$user1
 AND a.mutual=1
 UNION
 SELECT b.second_user_id
 FROM userprofile_usercontact b
 WHERE b.second_user_id=$user1
 AND b.mutual=1) as user1_contacts,
(SELECT a.first_user_id as uid
 FROM userprofile_usercontact a
 WHERE a.second_user_id=$user2
 AND a.mutual=1
 UNION
 SELECT b.second_user_id
 FROM userprofile_usercontact b
 WHERE b.second_user_id=$user2
 AND b.mutual=1) as user2_contacts
WHERE user1_contacts.uid=user2_contacts.uid
```

Effectively you're forcing a merge join, which may not be the most efficient solution (but will be a lot more efficient than trying to use 'IN' and 'OR'. It is possible to write the whole thing using nested lookups, but the code will get very messy.

If you want to go beyond a single degree of seperation, then it'd be a lot cleaner to use a [graph optimised DBMS](http://openquery.com/products/graph-engine)

Answer (score 0):

This is not pretty but it should work:

```
SELECT * FROM userprofile_usercontact 
WHERE 
(
first_user_id IN
(
/* get the first user's contacts */
SELECT second_user_id FROM userprofile_usercontact WHERE first_user_id = 1 AND mutual = 1
   UNION 
SELECT first_user_id FROM userprofile_usercontact WHERE second_user_id = 1 AND mutual = 1
) AND first_user_id IN (
/* get the second user's contacts */
SELECT second_user_id FROM userprofile_usercontact WHERE first_user_id = 37 AND mutual = 1
    UNION 
SELECT first_user_id FROM userprofile_usercontact WHERE second_user_id = 37 AND mutual = 1
)
) OR (
second_user_id IN
(
SELECT second_user_id FROM userprofile_usercontact WHERE first_user_id = 1 AND mutual = 1
   UNION 
SELECT first_user_id FROM userprofile_usercontact WHERE second_user_id = 1 AND mutual = 1
) AND second_user_id IN (
/* get the second user's contacts */
SELECT second_user_id FROM userprofile_usercontact WHERE first_user_id = 37 AND mutual = 1
    UNION 
SELECT first_user_id FROM userprofile_usercontact WHERE second_user_id = 37 AND mutual = 1
)
)
```